# Locking multiple CSS @keyframes animations together

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I've got some @keyframes animation and associated class name in CSS. For example, something like:

```
.fade {
    animation: fade 1.5s cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 0.6, 1) infinite;
}

@keyframes fade {
    0%, 100% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    50% {
        opacity: .5;
    }
}
```

If I show multiple elements with the .fade class applied, is there a way to lock them together so that they share the same position in the animation keyframes?

For instance, if I start with one `<div class="fade">` and happen to add a second when the first is hitting 50% in the animation, I want the second to start at 50%, so that everything fades in and out together.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be easier to give them unique class names or Id's so that you can target them individually , instead of as a group? This way you can tell #newname to chime in at appropriate keyframe of 50% and not cause issues with other elements. I could be misunderstanding your question. I am a beginner ,so I am sorry if i misled you, hopefully not...i do hope i am of some help. Good Luck!

Comment: Maybe this would have been better as a comment on the question. your post doesnt really give the OP a solution to their problem with code example...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm specifically looking for the ability to explicitly group them together without needing to manually tell each element "start now at keyframe X%". Even if I did want to go that route, I'm not sure there is actually a way for me to apply an animation starting at keyframe X%.